# How to specify generic type as a generic (higher kinded types)

Tags: typescript

In Typescript, is it possible to specify a generic type as generic? Specifically, I would like to be able to define a function signature as follows:

```
function events<T>(): T<Event>
```

However I am receiving the following error from the typescript compiler:

```
[ts] Type 'T' is not generic.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"generic type as a generic": if I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve is to use *higher kinded types*.

This not (yet) possible in Typescript: [see this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm looking for. Shame that it's not yet possible. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score -1):

Change the definition as below:

```
function events<T>(): Event<T>
```

Read more about the syntax here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Comment: No, sorry I want exactly what I asked in my question. T must be a generic, e.g. Stream<> or Observable<>