# Typescript infer generics within generics

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

## Problem

Let's say I have an interface `Wrapped`:

```js
interface Wrapped<T> {
  data: T
}
```

And I want to define a function like this:

```js
function f<T>(arg: any): T {
  const obj: Wrapped<T> = doSomethingAndGetWrappedObject<T>(arg)
  return obj.data
}

// Don't pay attention to the argument, it is not important for the question
const n: number = f<number>(/* ... */)
```

The problem is, in my application it is very inconvenient to pass `number` as type argument, I would like to pass `Wrapped<number>` instead, i.e. to call `f` like this:

```js
const n: number = f<Wrapped<number>>(/* ... */)
```

The question is: how to type `f` to make it possible?

### What I've tried

```js
function f<T extends Wrapped<V>, V>(arg: any) {
  // ...
}
// Now this works, but it is very annoying to write the second type argument
const n: number = f<Wrapped<number>, number>() 
// I would like to do this, but it produces an error
// Typescript accepts either no type arguments or all of them
const n: number = f<Wrapped<number>>()
```

```js
// This just works in an unpredictable way
function f<T extends Wrapped<any>>(
  arg: any
): T extends Wrapped<infer V> ? V : any {
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37323581/how-to-specify-generic-type-as-a-generic-higher-kinded-types/37323987#37323987

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create helper type for extracting the generic type by using `infer` keyword.

```
interface Wrapped<T> {
  data: T
}

type ExtractGeneric<T> = T extends Wrapped<infer X> ? X : never

function f<T extends Wrapped<any>>(): ExtractGeneric<T> {
  ....
}

const n = f<Wrapped<number>>()
```