# How to add a constraint on a map in a generic?

Tags: typescript, generics, constraints

**Edit**: I wasn't clear enough, you might want to jump to the next example.

I've got an issue with constraints on generics and cannot grasp what I'm doing wrong.
Basically, I'm trying this:

```
enum Categories {
    FIRST = 'first',
    SECOND = 'second',
}

type ItemsMap = {
    [key in Categories]: Item<key>;
}

class Item<
    T extends keyof M,
    M extends {[key in T]: Item<key, M>} = ItemsMap,
> {
    category: T;
    items: M;
}
```

The goal is to pass a "map" of enum/type (Item will later need to use the "type") which seems to work great because VSCode shows me this:

```
type ItemsMap = {
    first: Item<Categories.FIRST, ItemsMap>;
    second: Item<Categories.SECOND, ItemsMap>;
}
```

Yet, I've got a TS error on the default of the M generic:

```
Type 'ItemsMap' does not satisfy the constraint '{ [key in T]: Item<key, ItemsMap>; }'
```

Why doesn't it satisfy the constraint?

I've got another issue when trying to use this map in a subclass:

```
class Foo<M extends {[key in keyof M]: Item<key, M>}> {} // OK
class Bar<M extends ItemsMap = ItemsMap> extends Foo<M> {} // Not OK
class Baz extends Foo<ItemsMap> {} // OK, but why?
```

TS yield an error on Bar:

```
Type 'M' does not satisfy the constraint '{ [key in keyof M]: Item<key, M>; }'.
    Type 'ItemsMap' is not assignable to type '{ [key in keyof M]: Item<key, M>; }'.
```

But I don't understand why.
Is there a way to have more information from TS?

---

Let's use another example, it might be better to understand my issue.
Let's take an event:

```
interface EventInterface {
    target: EventTargetInterface;
    type: string;
}
```

So far it's pretty simple, an event have a type and a target (the object that emitted the event). The later is described as follows:

```
interface EventTargetInterface {
    addEventListener(type: string, listener: (event: EventInterface) => void): void;
    dispatchEvent(event: EventInterface): boolean;
    removeEventListener(type: string, listener: (event: EventInterface) => void): void;
}
```

The `addEventListener` method, for example, is callable with a string and a function taking something like an `EventInterface`.

From that point, I want to add some constraints for multiple reasons:

- To disallow using a type and an incompatible listener
- To restrict the types
- To type-hint to the developers ("you can only use these types"; "if you use this type, the listener will/should be this type", etc.)

To do so, I want the developer to define a mapped type:

```
type EventsMap = {
    first: NiceEvent;
    second: AwesomeEvent;
}
```

This mapped type is here to say: "For the event type 'first', it will dispatch a 'NiceEvent'". This should be only a type and not generating code.

So, I changed my `EventTargetInterface` like this:

```
interface EventTargetInterface<
    M extends {[key in keyof M]: EventInterface},
> {
    addEventListener<T extends keyof M>(type: T, listener: (event: M[T]) => void): void;
    dispatchEvent<T extends M[keyof M]>(event: T): boolean;
    removeEventListener<T extends keyof M>(type: T, listener: (event: M[T]) => void): void;
}
```

So far, so good, this should constraint the type to only keys of the "given" map and the listener will be tied to it.
But now, `EventTargetInterface` takes a generic, so I have to change `EventInterface` as well:

```
interface EventInterface<
    M extends {[key in keyof M]: EventInterface<M>},
> {
    target: EventTargetInterface<M>;
    type: keyof M;
}
```

OK, looking good. Let's add a base implementation now:

```
abstract class EventBase<
    M extends {[key in keyof M]: EventInterface<M>},
> implements EventInterface<M> {
    target: EventTargetInterface<M>;
    type: keyof M;

    constructor(type: keyof M) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}

abstract class EventTargetBase<
    M extends {[key in keyof M]: EventInterface<M>},
> implements EventTargetInterface<M> {
    addEventListener<T extends keyof M>(type: T, listener: (event: M[T]) => void): void {}
    dispatchEvent<T extends M[keyof M]>(event: T): boolean { return false; }
    removeEventListener<T extends keyof M>(type: T, listener: (event: M[T]) => void): void {}
}
```

And now, the first concrete implementation:

```
enum MyEvents {
    FIRST = 'first',
    SECOND = 'second',
}

type MyEventsMap = {
    [key in MyEvents]: MyEvent;
}

class MyEvent<
    M extends MyEventsMap = MyEventsMap,
> extends EventBase<M> {}

class MyEventTarget<
    M extends MyEventsMap = MyEventsMap,
> extends EventTargetBase<M> {}
```

And this is here that I have an issue (on `extends EventBase<M>` and `EventTargetBase<M>`):

```
Type 'M' does not satisfy the constraint '{ [key in keyof M]: EventInterface<M>; }'.
  Type 'MyEventsMap' is not assignable to type '{ [key in keyof M]: EventInterface<M>; }'.ts(2344)
```

So, for Typescript something extending `MyEventsMap` does not conform to `M extends {[key in keyof M]: EventInterface<M>}`. But I don't understand because `MyEvent` extends `EventBase` which implements `EventInterface`!

Even more confusing, using:

```
class MyEvent extends EventBase<MyEventsMap> {}
```

This is fine for Typescript, so I don't get what is going wrong when using the generic. (I need to keep the generic as I want my class to be extendable but that's another topic)

You can access the [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIDcLgJLmvJAHgCgBIAWWQgA9IQATAZ2QG8BtAawgE9lRku3APYxk5ALoAuNJhx5YiCIXIA+AL4AaYitZkwcKAHMIYaRixgAKgeNhckBUVXIAPshABXADZeA3Hu4ABwhpQRExfzViYgQvOEZmc3AAIXilMkoaOiZWTh4+EAEecIkzWTt5AiVVTW0+AFtArwh6i0Ty+3xFZR0WPRsTMotrIxNOx2qdN08fZABed28-AODQ4tFyf1IEIRBGMCgPBDAhKAAKMCCQouENgEpdUlIwAAtgRgA6S+D55G+ILZRKLEUAOKoyYYDCpg7oZKi0LA5diCAo3EpSCFyGFOdRaXpkOD0ehJMAAGXedGghEs8OyzDCGxUFyu0ksGmQXgpWGg0jOEHK0nIbEs4gecx06CEwHod2kkulW3o70CcDACBeJOptMRzCFDLE4iZ-IsrNlyAARkIhM04CAtlAWkJMCTyftuVAtVkdWjGczVsg2RyuSAecg+QKxMLRfMJVKZXK45FonBzfsoIgwMhYvF2pDRmBUox0hRtQxmMj8vx9aVMdCujjajpgI1mq1wLnwCNbOMqj1HoTieVXZSPTSvWWfWImf9WezOW6Q1BecbwIKo2LY9KzfL6KwoqQlYwVWqNeVPQiJ3r1gajRHLGbLdaILbWMgHWAPFBCvAvEXfMh9wdeonQgF1gypMcLxyatpxZAM53ApcwxXUxIxFDdkB3bc4z3YhgSwDx6jEbgSXLMgADFsAAJQAZRpBYAHIYGAKB9gYrRSBo1AAGEAHkADkABFfgYosdgYdi8Oif5iNI8g4ECX4+lIPJeH4cgSPKRgMQ0kkkxiOIElks84XHHJdK0+TFIWCy2isvFSxyElC0mXCDJzYy81sEgSzM3VNLshTfls9t7LqPzay7EwXL7FgoiAA) if you want to fiddle with it.

Comment: Is the circularity of `ItemsMap` map necessary/intentional? I'm not sure it's valid. Also the generic type `Item` has one type arg in one context, and two in the other. That can't be right.  I'm just learning Typescript, so maybe I'm wrong about that. Can you explain in plain english what a `Type` is and what a `TypesMap` is? Being able to do so is a good rule for object oriented design.

Comment: Yes, the circularity is intentional as I need to pass the generic to another type. `Item` is declared only with one generic in a context because the second generic have a default value so it's not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

## UPD

Ok, now I understand what you want, but there are still some questions about how your objects are supposed to behave at runtime. Also you have **a lot** of circular dependency going on. It's very hard to deal with, and, honestly, I've got no idea what typescript is trying to do with your code.

The main problem that prevents me from making up a reasonable answer is not the generics, but object properties that produce indefinite nesting. 
Mainly, the `target` property on `EventInterface` interface, what is it supposed to be? Is it the same `EventTargetInterface` that dispatched the event? Is it another `EventTargetInterface`? In both cases, how do you initialize the `target` property? So I was actually able to make your example (kinda?) work in [TS sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIDcLgCpygcwjAElxp4kAeAKGWQFlkIAPSEAEwGdkBvWu5AHpByAApxOnUPmQADMAE8ADhAD2MZAGsIC2cgDuAC2AJDyYNzCGU85RD3rkVlBEzh+dANraFALmScYFDSALr+GFgkZLCIEJSKKo4+ADQMAHz8AL7UabweyHDs7BHgADIWbNCU2EysWFxaOo70aQAUCRD+2KkANhVY0P6trpH+9J7YIQCUyAC8ueiqwOxT-ovLANz57BZKcGCmJWDVtWwN4z7NIW0j4F2ryABGqqo9EHAgWwLIUBAAtqpMEdyoEBlATiwztxLhoWu07F1ev0QINkMM3GAxhNpnMFksVmt8VtstRQJAYkg0BjSOSKHF+MJkNhjNwLE5rHIOg4NM4mBj+DVIfVuIFgiB8MkGSJmWzCCjgghzNwAK6cCBvSTIGCqKByI408ixWRS8xgADk3FUIB6CmQSmVUCUqjVSqcqjtElZYDdeoxuAIRANFLiLWNdEYQo43D4328On8otC4Wp0TplET4tSLSyOTy3zAeEImKpkX9RaDaZaXwEHS6xOo1Dgj1FiG9CB6npL4AAQhJ6XRBXUowEgtJJeHTsK8wI434R2L8GEu1FabFqlmMnRsrlgH8lG8-pFuPrU2vuulpwgraLlQgwDrWvl7Y8+ora0zxwJn6+nIWiMnSz-FdDSobM6BmHhkGyEkmxbO9kHbTsjjLIhezVGgJ0jBoYxnHwE1HcUlxPVcqA6JIdA3HMdz3A8j2XFDgODSgWmnQpigxEFKnBQcoUaBRmjafJ326fI+lBeUhluYtxkmGZ5mQdZ2H4B5FN4KD+B2Tg9gOQwjkfb4pKxGEGBCZT-GeV53hANTfjAB1rPgHo1Q2dS6F+AEgQ45Eqh4qdjLhISEQ-UTvKgSSMSxWTcQU-EzJi5Y1OghssGVP4GAUI5o3yAAxYgACUAGUalmZAzRgYAoECM1PzoArUAAYQAeQAOQAETmUq1SvDhquoEkOnSzL6DgJQOpw2dzGs+gMoxTgl2mo562oRlWtUCBOBAM1vX0HVNHMDR+OVAoimQOVoBMSx3VkBaMWNRDNRuyJJ2HI40JDGajyzD7wE4YalFyHhskZABBJz3XYNaNu23b9uQQ7jvYU6wQu6h7u4R6cCA56GmQoC3uY76wF+kaAZJbrAl-ANvRKlF9EGv0gNaKZUevb1XGp5BafpyJWgxomADpcsK88Cyp5nqFFot+c07TDgxdEwGZyWiH5tjgVC3nCc4QX8qK1IFbkgHkH4dn+Y6PqpiAA), **but** you should really think of changing your design in some way. These circular dependencies are really hard to deal with, and I have no idea if this will work as expected in all cases, these generics are very unstable. This can cause the developers more headache than help.

#### Reason of the error

So the main reason lies in the end of error, it says

```
'MyEventsMap' is assignable to the constraint of type 'M', but 'M' could
be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'MyEventsMap'.
```

For example, take the following function

```
function fn<T extends string | number>(): T {
  return "I don't work"
}
```

This will produce a similar error

```
'"I don't work"' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T'
could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string | number'.
```

The reason should be obvious, `T` is not guaranteed to include `string` type, I could as well call it as `fn<number>()` or `fn<1>()` and it won't work. The thing about typescript that caused me a lot of pain in the neck is the fact **you cannnot prevent calling function/instantiating class/using type alias/do anything concerning generics with a subtype of the contraint in `extends` clause**. This is not completely true, there is a hack, using helper types like

```
type EnsureMyMap<T> = T extends MyEventsMap<infer M> ? MyEventsMap<M> : never
```

I've posted a question on this topic. It's not exactly suitable for this case, but it shows the idea. You can check it out and read the best answer for a [concrete example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61153711/typescript-infer-generics-within-generics).

Honestly, no idea, how this applies to your particular example, and I have no wish to dig into it. Maybe it is because of the default value you specify for the generic in `MyEvent` and `MyEventTarget`, but I'm not sure. You probably could fix everything with this `infer` keyword and helper types after an hour or two of struggling, but is it worth it?

So my suggestion would be to rethink the design of these classes. Particularly it would be nice to get rid of the `target` property on the event, which causes all of that circular dependency stuff. Maybe you don't need it? Maybe you could pass it alongside with the event? Another option would be to go less strict with the contraints and reduce headache in the future at the cost of worse type hints (I mean getting rid of this event map entirely). I may update the answer again, if you need help on redesigning all of that, I just need a runtime example, not only ambient type declaration. That's all I can suggest for now.

## Original answer

Your code seems a bit strange. There are lots of circular references. Firstly, I suppose, that in the second code snippet, the type should have a different name, otherwise `ItemsMap`, as suggested in the comments by Inigo, references itself:

```
type MyMap = {
    first: Item<Categories.FIRST, ItemsMap>;
    second: Item<Categories.SECOND, ItemsMap>;
}
```

Even if this is the case, I don't think, that even if the code you wrote worked, it would do what it is supposed to do. Suppose you make a variable

```
const map: MyMap = { first: /*...*/, second: /*...*/ }
```

So what is `map.first` supposed to be? An object like

```
{ 
  category: Categories.FIRST, 
  items: /*...*/
}
```

So what is `map.first.items`? An `ItemsMap`, for example `{ [Category.FIRST]: /*...*/ }`. So what is `map.first.items[Category.FIRST]`? An object like

```
{
  category: Category.FIRST,
  items: /* ... */
}
```

Now go back to the previous paragraph and another `[Category.FIRST].items` to the property I wrote the question about.

So that just goes on forever. It does stop, if you assign an empty object to `items` at one point, but anyways it doesn't seem like you want an indefinitely nested tree of items and categories. Sorry if you do, it's just not clear from you code and explanations.

So the only thing I can suppose is that you didn't what to use `Item` class in the definition of `ItemsMap`. In this case it would make some sense for me. You just stated

> The goal is to pass a "map" of enum/type

So I think you mean you want to make an object something like this (if `Item` in `ItemsMap` definition is replaced with `{ id: key }`, for example):

```
const map = {
  first: {
    category: 'first',
    items: { 
      first: { id: 'first' },
      second: { id: 'second' },
    },
  },
  second: {
    category: 'second',
    items: {
      first: { id: 'first' },
      second: { id: 'second' },
    },
  },
}
```

Even here, it doesn't make much sense to me, why you want your keys to be from the same set in `map` object and all `map[...].items` objects. Again, sorry if that's not what you meant, I will update my answer if you provide a better explanation of your goals. Also show an example of an object of the type you want to define.

Comment: I edited my post with another example, tell me if it's still unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand the end goal (perhaps a few more usage examples could help).
However, the way I currently interpret the task... does this solve it?

```
class Item<
    T extends string,
    K extends string = Categories,
> {
    category: T;
    items: Record<K, Item<T, K>>;
}
```

Comment: I edited my post with another example, tell me if it's still unclear.

Comment: Thanks. The intention seems clearer, but I still don't get it how you plan to use it. Where will you define that type "first" maps to FirstEventTarget and "second" maps to SecondEventTarget? It's not in the example code

Answer (score 0):

well an easy way to have a typed key map is by:

```js
type Categories = "SECOND" | "FIRST";

const myMap = new Map<Categories, string>();
myMap.set("FOURTH", "Fourth");
myMap.set("FIRST", "Fourth");
myMap.set("SECOND", "Fourth");
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. I edited my post; I'd rather have a mapped type than a Map (the first one will generate 0 code while the second will generate some)